# Django NoReverseMatch error in RedirectView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have been attempting to make a follow feature for my site, however I am consistently getting stuck on errors.
Here is the UserProfileInfo model

```py
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,allow_unicode=True)
# ... other fields

def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug':self.user.username,
        }
        return reverse('mainapp:view_profile_with_pk',kwargs=kwargs)
        # return reverse('mainapp:post_list')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my view

```py
class AddFriendRedirect(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserProfileInfo,slug=slug)
        # user_profile = User.objects.get(username=username)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user in obj.friends.all():
                obj.friends.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.friends.add(user)
        return url_
```

Here is my `urls.py`

```py
path('profile/<str:username>/',views.view_profile,name='view_profile_with_pk'), # this one is the profile one
path('profile/<str:slug>/add/',views.AddFriendRedirect.as_view(),name='add_friend'),
```

And finally here is my HTML

```html
<a id="new-post" href="{% url 'mainapp:add_friend' slug=username %}">
        <button id="">
            Connect
        </button>
```

And here is my error

> NoReverseMatch at /mainapp/profile/don0024/add/
>
> Reverse for 'view_profile_with_pk' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'don0024'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['mainapp/profile/(?P[^/]+)/$']

And the full traceback

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainapp/profile/don0024/add/
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view
>     71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in get
>     188.         url = self.get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\interests-site\interests\mainapp\views.py" in
>   get_redirect_url
>     227.         url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
>
> File "C:\Users\User\interests-site\interests\mainapp\models.py" in
>   get_absolute_url
>     72.         return reverse('mainapp:view_profile_with_pk',kwargs=kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py"
>   in reverse
>     90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py"
>   in _reverse_with_prefix
>     673.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
>
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /mainapp/profile/don0024/add/
>   Exception Value: Reverse for 'view_profile_with_pk' with keyword
>   arguments '{'slug': 'don0024'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['mainapp/profile/(?P[^/]+)/$']

I'm sorry if this is a lot of code and errors, but any help would be great

Comment: Can you show `view_profile_with_pk` urls as well?

Comment: added it with the other url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing kwargs wrongly to the reverse function. Here is the correct way to pass username into `view_profile_with_pk` url.

```
kwargs = {
    'username': self.user.username,
}
return reverse('mainapp:view_profile_with_pk',kwargs=kwargs)
```

Comment: I did this, however I now get a 404 error saying that the page doesn't exist

Comment: Can you check the `view_profile` function to ensure that render correctly. Also please provide complete traceback.

Comment: You wouldn't believe it, but now it works without errors, however it is not updating in the database. It redirects and then that's it. It doesn't add the user to the manytomanyfield

Comment: I'm not sure about your models' relation and your method of saving so I can't guess.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to do it originally

Comment: No problem. Glad that I can help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `kwargs` in `get_absolute_url` as below...

```
kwargs = {
             'username':self.user.username,
         }
```

Because you set `username` in your urls.py, not slug.

```
path('profile/<str:username>/',views.view_profile,name='view_profile_with_pk')
path('profile/<slug:slug>/add/',views.AddFriendRedirect.as_view(),name='add_friend'),
```

So, when it will try to set `slug` it will not find `slug` because you set `<str:username>` in your url.